# How to add function definition in Lua without requiring that a file be loaded?

Tags: lua

I am using the C Fuzzy API and I want to load function module contained in a file lets say mycalculator.lua.  This seem to run fine however when I later try to run another file A.lua that requires 'mycalculator' it does not work unless the mycalculator.lua file is available on the file system to reload.  I am trying to just load it into the system and then have it available without having the mycalculator.lua in the file system. It there any way to have lua system keep the definition without loading it again? Basically I convert the mycalculator.lua into a string and then run it.  I don't want to put mycalculator.lua file into the file system, I just want to hand it over as a string and then be able to require it in the next string I pass to the stack  Thanks

Comment: What *do* you have a place to put that string on? Strings don't exist magically on a file system, they always require some kind of storage. How do you plan to execute A.lua?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between simply executing a Lua script and loading a Lua module. If you wish to load a Lua module, then you must actually load a Lua module exactly as a script would: by calling `require`.

Since you appear to be new to Lua, I should probably explain this. You've probably seen code like this in Lua scripts:

```
require 'mycalculator'
```

That is not some special statement to Lua. That is a *function call*. It is just some syntactic sugar for:

```
require('mycalculator')
```

Functions in Lua can be called with `NAME VALUE` syntax instead of `NAME(...)` syntax, but it only allows you to send one parameter. And the parameter must be a literal (or table constructor).

In order to call the Lua `require` function from C, you must use the Lua stack. You must fetch the function from the global table by using `lua_getfield(L, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "require");` Then, you push a string onto the stack containing the name of the module to load. Then, you use `lua_pcall` or whatever Lua function calling function to call it.

Comment: Ok. Well I am interested in loading/requiring the module and passing this requirement in as a string. I want to pass a string that contains the content of the module that is required so that lua never goes to the file system for that module. Can this be done?

Comment: So in requiring loading I don't want lua to check the file system but instead I want to pass this module as a string.

Comment: So what I am asking is I don't want to use something like the following: path = "./path/to/a/file.lua"

Comment: Instead, I want to provide the file contents to lua.

Comment: I have reposted in terms of LUA Java and loading a string:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599597/how-do-i-load-lua-file-as-a-string