# Lua create own loadstring() function

Tags: serialization, lua, coronasdk

loadstring() and loadfile() Lua functions allow loading remote libraries and modules at runtime. As shown in this post it is very simple: [How Do I Load Lua Module as a String Instead of a File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599597/)

Unfortunately Corona SDK has removed both these function. [Here's a list](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/changes-lua) of changes they have.

Is it possible to implement loadstring in lua or load it from a separate module?
They seem to provide a solution here but I don't really understand it and I don't think it will work in Corona cause it requires dofile which is also disabled in Corona
http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-04/msg00875.html

Comment: You can still use `require`?

Comment: require cannot handle a file url outside resource directory. So it does not work to load remote modules

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by remote modules?

Comment: yes, it means loading modules stored in a server, for example the module could be in `http://myserver/source/myawesomemodule.lua` and it would be loaded the following way: `local awesomeModule=loadfile(http.require"http://myserver/source/myawesomemodule.lua")` instated of `require("myawesomemodule.lua")`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

loadstring() and dofile() are disabled per Apple's rules for allowing interpreted language apps to work on their devices.  Apple will reject any app that has any dynamic programming features.

Comment: I only mean to use it during development. Is there a way to have those functions available again? I noticed that they are available in Corona Enterprise but it would be cool to have them in Corona Pro as well.

Comment: Why does bash work?